# How to create .jar library from class in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, package

I am trying to learn java and have implemented a single, and simple, class in Intellij IDEA 14.1.3. I want to be able to use this class in other projects without copy and pasting the class source into each project src directory. Essentially, I want to create a package, or module (I'm not sure which, which is part of the problem) that I can simply import into any projects's src that I am working on--kind of like my own, one-class, library. While trying to figure out how to do this, I came across the two following blog posts--

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/10/new-in-11-create-library-from-project-view/
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

--but when I tried to do what they instructed (creating artifacts in Project structure, etc.) I wasn't able to because my class doesn't have a main() method, as its not meant to. So I was wondering if I was going about this right--is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with copying and pasting?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the need you encountered for `main()`? Why do you think it is required? Did you get an error message that said so? At which point in the experiments?

Comment: Change your question. "Do java classes have to have main methods to become packages?" is so wrong and has nothing to do with the two tutorials you mentionen. These tutorials are about creating a project (1) and quick-create a jar artifact. So the Q should be "Do I need a class with a `main()` method in order to create a jar artifact"

Comment: Edit done, thanks Alexander. Also, I think I am getting confused because, when I right-click on the project (or anything really) in the solution explorer, it has the option 'Make Module x' and I don't understand what that means exactly, or if its necessary to create a .jar library, since below Stultuske said modules aren't really used in Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get it--I had to go into Project Structure and set it to create a jar file containing my compiled .class file upon build. Then I could add the jar file as an external library in my other projects. Thanks guys for the replies.

Comment: What steps did you take in order to include the compiled .class file in the jar?

Comment: Oh jeez, it's been awhile, and I'm sure IntelliJ has changed its layout and navigation since 2015, but I seem to remember that 'Project Structure' was an option in one of the drop-down menus at the top of IntelliJ-- either that, or a sidebar option in 'Project Settings' or something of the like. I'm afraid that's all I can recall.

Answer (score 3):

You only need a main method if you want the package to be able to run as a standalone application.

So, to answer your question: no.

You don't need a main method to create a package, nor to import or use the package/library in a separate application.

Comment: So it is a package I'm after, not a module? As in, I can just import it and start using it right away

Comment: depends on what you are talking about? The term 'module' is not really used in Java (at least not that I know). I think you mean a library (a .jar file) which might contain tons of packages.
A package on it's own is just a part of an application. You can't import a package itself, unless it's in the classpath already, and to get it there, it has to be either in the project itself, either in an imported project, or in an imported jar file

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean--my question is how to go from a .java class, to a .jar library with that class in it.

Comment: here you'll find all you need to know to do it by command line, but I assume your IDE has functionalities to do this for you. Normally, if you build, it'll generate a .jar for your project.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Personally, though, I am not pro using an IDE if you don't have good knowledge of the basics yet.